# wp_head() not inserting the default stylesheet style.css

Tags: theme-development, css, wp-head, customization

I have a custom theme with just a name in its `style.css`. I've activated it in admin which shows it just fine.

In the `index.php` just `<?php wp_head(); ?>` and it doesn't output the line that is supposed to include my main stylesheet `style.css`:

```css
<link rel='stylesheet' id='my-theme'  href='~/wp-content/themes/my-theme/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

It prints out all the other stuff ***but*** that line! What would make it not print out my default stylesheet inclusion line?

---

`style.css` :

```
/*
Theme Name: my-theme
*/
```

`index.php` :

```php
hello world
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

output:

> ```
> hello world
> <meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
> <link rel='stylesheet' id='open-sans-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=4.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
> <link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='~/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
> <link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='~/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
> <link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="~/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
> <link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="~/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
> <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.0" />
> <style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
> <style type="text/css" media="screen">
>     html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
>     * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
>     @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
>         html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
>         * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
>     }
> </style>
> ```

Comment: You should not add these in `index.php` but these must be already in `header.php` and `<?php wp_head(); ?>` must be first line in index.php or all other theme files.

Comment: try adding <?php wp_head(); ?> in your header.php <head> section.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you shouldn't add JS and CSS files to your `header.php`, but make use of the functions [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to add them there.

Example taken from the codex page:

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: I think his theme must be including CSS files that way but I think he is more concerned about `style.css` is being empty and not being included in website.

Comment: You might be right. But: For one the style.css shouldn't be empty anyway, it should at least contain the [header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet). Secondly it doesn't need to be included into the head, it can of course, but does need to be present in the themes directory. Last but not least, it's just always preferable to do it the way I suggested. I just added it so others coming here can know about that. @Roberthue

Comment: Btw inserting the `style.css` via `wp_enqueue_style` does normally work just fine, even if there is only the header in it - so there must be another problem why it didn't work. @Roberthue Aside from that, I answered your question some days ago, did you take a look?

Comment: sorry I did not notice your answer. I will check it now. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem and no hurry, I just realized it was you, so I thought I ask :) @Roberthue

Answer (score -1):

You should add your .js and .css files, like this. in your `header.php`

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='my-theme' href='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Did you notice `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` in above code that you will need to use. It defines URL to theme folder on your website. You can add all other files links similarly.

Although it's not necessary to include /theme/style.css in your website unless it has any styles for website to use. I think your theme use this style.css file only for information/define theme variable purposes.